# Symfony: Is it possible to put elements inside a link_to tag?

Tags: symfony1, tags, hyperlink, helper

I'm using Symfony 1.4 and wondering whether it's possible to achieve the following:

```
<a href="#"><span>Text</span></a>
```

... using Symfony's link_to helper?

Of course, it's possible to do this:

```
<a href="<?php echo url_for('#') ?>"><span>Text</span></a>
```

But I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to do it, especially as combining i18n with the above will produce:

```
<a href="<?php echo url_for('#') ?>"><span><?php echo __('Text') ?></span></a>
```

... a tag soup basically.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YOu can do it two ways...

Option 1

```
<?php echo link_to("<span>".__('Text')."</span>", $url); ?>
```

Option 2

```
<?php echo content_tag('a',  "<span>".__('Text')."</span>", array('href' => url_for($url))); ?>
```

Comment: Mind you you may need to do something with the escaping for `link_to` im not completely sure - its been awhile.

Answer (score 1):

There's also:

```
<?php echo link_to(content_tag('span', __'Text', array('class' => 'span-class')), '@route', array('class' => 'link-class'));
```

I added the attribute `class` for each of the two HTML tags as options if you need to extend that way.